# Cannot get tracking of compose functions

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, tracking

I have found some friezes when I scrolled LazyColumn with some Image items. I have implemented this libraкy, but I still cannot get tracking

```
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-tracing:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

What am i doing wrong? I have tested on a device with 33-android version also have tried testing on emulations with 33 and 32 versions

my app gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
}

android {
    namespace "io.complitech.viewer"
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
        if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
            def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
            keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
            release {
                storeFile = rootProject.file(keystoreProperties.getProperty("storeFile"))
                storePassword = keystoreProperties.getProperty("storePassword")
                keyAlias = keystoreProperties.getProperty("keyAlias")
                keyPassword = keystoreProperties.getProperty("keyPassword")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion composeCompileVersion
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

composeCompileVersion = 1.4.3
composeVersion = 1.4.3
studio version = Giraffe | 2022.3.1
```

Comment: "friezes" > app freezes ? "libraкy" > library ?